# linear layout are not getting divided equally when the text width inside them are changing

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout (horizontal) inside which there is 3 linear layouts, each of them have a textview inside them.

Now I wanted to divide these linear layouts equally. So I added weight to them as 1. It works perfect.

But now when the text width inside them are varying they are no more of equal weight :(

Say for any linear layout i removed the text, or wrote a smaller text or varying length text then it is loosing the equal distribution.
What do I do to make the layouts uniformly distributed.

And one more thing i would like to know say the text width increases the max allocated width for these layout (these will be given dynamically may be by doing width = 1), then how do i move the text to next line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you set the width to 0dip for each item inside the LinearLayout.

Comment: wow.. this works and thanks. but one quick question. what is the significance of 0dip ?

Comment: It sets the size to 0. Weight is used to share the remaining empty space after Views have been measured. So if you set them all to 0, the empty space is the entire container.